# Uploading an Image File from React to Laravel (API)

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am trying to post a new Member(User) form with an image to the Members table in Laravel. I cant seem to be able to get the correct controller and validation to work on Laravel. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
`import React, { useState, Component, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class UploadImage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
          image: ''
        }
        // this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
        this.handleFileUpload = this.handleFileUpload.bind(this)
        this.handleFileHandler = this.handleFileHandler.bind(this)
      }

    handleFileUpload = (event) =>{
        console.log(event.target.files[0])
        this.setState({
            image:event.target.files[0]
        })
    };


    handleFileHandler = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", this.state.image);

        axios.put('http://band_app.test/api/file/1/image_list',formData)
        .then(response=> {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
        })
    };

    render() {

      return (
        <form encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={this.handleFileHandler}>
        <input onChange={this.handleFileUpload} type="file" name="image"/>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
      </form>
      );
    }
  }

  export default UploadImage;`
```

Comment: Please Include just enough code to allow us to understand the problem. Do check, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `    public function memberImageSave(MemberRequest $request, Member $member)
    {
        $member->update($this->validateImageRequest());

        $this->storeImage($member);
    }


    }`

Comment: private function validateImageRequest()
    {
        //if statement has been added to make it optional for IMAGE
        if(request()->hasFile('image')){
            return request()-> validate([
                'image' => 'file|image|max:5000',
            ]);
        }
    }

Comment: private function storeImage()
    {
        if(request()->has('image')){
            $member->update([
                'image' => request()->image->store('uploads','public'),
            ]);
        }

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Thanks @AjeetShah Ive managed to get it working! Had left out a reference within the Save Function in Laravel